# How can I convert this openssl command in ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I am trying to convert this command to ruby code using `OpenSSL`:

```
openssl s_client -verify_hostname www.example.com -connect example.com:443
```

I've pieced together that openssl has a verify_hostname method but I dont think that I am using this properly. Contextually I have a problem verifying a domain's SAN field. For a given domain I get wrong results. I provide a domain that is clearly a name mismatch buy I get a `verify_result` code of 0 which is ok. The command above gives me the right information but I can't seem to get this to translate in ruby. Is there an online tool that can convert this for me?

Answer (score 1):

`-verify_hostname` is a parameter and `s_client` is a method name in your command. Check the output of `openssl s_client --help` to get more information. [OpenSSL](https://github.com/ruby/openssl) gem has a [verify_hostname](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jruby-openssl/OpenSSL%2FSSL.verify_hostname) method but its source code looks like it's only checking if provided strings are correct, it does not call the provided host.

All http clients will do the SSL verification for you by default (unless you disable it):

```rb
require "net/http"

begin
  Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://expired.badssl.com"))
rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
  puts "bad ssl cert"
end
```

If you'd like to to the exact thing as your command does you'd probably need to download host's certificate first and then instantiate it with `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new` verify it with the [check_validity](https://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/ruby-library/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html) method.